# getting the wrong index when I search something on the searcher

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

This is an example to explain a problem that I’m having.

I have 3 elements in an array. the index of the array matches each sentences. Like

The 0 index matches “hello” (0 index)
The 1 index matches “nice” (1 index)
The 2 index matches “how are you?” (2 index)

I’ve put UISearchBar in my tableView. When I type “h” in the searchBar, “hello” and “how are you” show up perfectly, but the thing is, when I touch “how are you” which is 2 index on the tableview list, it shows “nice” on the next viewController (I have two viewControllers and the variable called myIndex use the index on the next viewController ) because the variable gets 1 index not 2 index. How should I solve this?

The full code is as follows :

```
  import UIKit

  class tableviewtest: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
               to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

}



var searchArr = [String]()
var searching = false

var copiedArray:[String] = eng  // eng is the original array that has the full elements from another view controller. 

let cellIdentifier = "xxx"


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for:indexPath)
    if searching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = searchArr[indexPath.row]

    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = copiedArray[indexPath.row]

    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchArr.count
    }
    else {
    return copiedArray.count
}
}

func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   myIndex = indexPath.row

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: self)
}


@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
    self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

  }

  }

extension tableviewtest: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBar (_ searchBar:UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText:     String) {
    searchArr = copiedArray.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) ==      searchText})
   searching = true
      tableview.reloadData()
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you get the string from the array you have to consider the `searching` state

```
let selectedItem = searching ? searchArr[myIndex] : filteredArr[myIndex]
```

and you have to *reset* `searching` if the search string is empty

```
func searchBar (_ searchBar:UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        searching = false
        searchArr.removeAll()
    } else {
        searchArr = filteredArr.filter({$0.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText})
        searching = true
    }
    tableview.reloadData()
 }
```

---

You could even pass the string as `sender` parameter in `performSegue` and hand it over to the next view controller in `prepare(for segue`

```
func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedItem = searching ? searchArr[indexPath.row] : filteredArr[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: selectedItem)
}
```

Side note:

Reconsider your naming of the variables: Why is the data source array once called `filteredArr` and then `numberOfRows`, and why is the non-filtered array called  `filteredArr` anyway?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried it but the result was the same as I had tried before. I think I should stop using indexPath.row because it returns the row number?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code how you pass the string to the next controller. Yes it returns the row number of the current data source array.

Comment: I added the full code and changed the variable name. The array "eng" has many sentences, and when I search "h", I see there's a lot of sentences that starts with "h" successfully, and when I touch a sentence that starts with h on the 3rd row of the tableView which is actually 12th index of the array "eng", the variable "myIndex" gets the second index, maybe because I touched the 3rd row on the tableview. the variable "myIndex" has to bring 12th index.. not 2..